# After upgrade to MySQL 8, JSON large queries fail

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-8.0

After upgrading to MySQL 8 w/ the Ubuntu 20.04 distribution upgrade, any MySQL JSON data type queries returning a large JSON data payload are failing when using primary keys to sort/order. The Java SQL exception chain I get starts with a Out of sort memory exception. I set the sort buffer to 1024K but do not know if I should increase my sort buffer much based on things I have read saying setting the sort buffer large can cause performance issues. I am doing minor sorting on data using a primary key, and it's still causing the sort buffer error. I can remove the sort by Date clause and it works, but it's not the order I want the data in. Is it because I need to create a Primary key in the subquery I'm creating somehow?

`java.sql.SQLException: Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size`

The query I am trying to run is as follows:

```
SELECT
                Date, Type, GeoJSON FROM (
                SELECT Date, 'R' AS Type, RunGeoJSON as GeoJSON FROM Core.Fitness WHERE RunGeoJSON IS NOT NULL AND (CommonRoute = 0 OR CommonRoute IS NULL) UNION ALL
                SELECT Date, 'C' AS Type, CycGeoJSON as GeoJSON FROM Core.Fitness WHERE CycGeoJSON IS NOT NULL AND (CommonRoute = 0 OR CommonRoute IS NULL) UNION ALL
                SELECT Date, 'A' AS Type, AltGeoJSON as GeoJSON FROM Core.Fitness WHERE AltGeoJSON IS NOT NULL AND (CommonRoute = 0 OR CommonRoute IS NULL)) as tmp
                ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

But if I simply just remove the order by, like this, I don't get the sort buffer error:

```
SELECT
                Date, Type, GeoJSON FROM (
                SELECT Date, 'R' AS Type, RunGeoJSON as GeoJSON FROM Core.Fitness WHERE RunGeoJSON IS NOT NULL AND (CommonRoute = 0 OR CommonRoute IS NULL) UNION ALL
                SELECT Date, 'C' AS Type, CycGeoJSON as GeoJSON FROM Core.Fitness WHERE CycGeoJSON IS NOT NULL AND (CommonRoute = 0 OR CommonRoute IS NULL) UNION ALL
                SELECT Date, 'A' AS Type, AltGeoJSON as GeoJSON FROM Core.Fitness WHERE AltGeoJSON IS NOT NULL AND (CommonRoute = 0 OR CommonRoute IS NULL)) as tmp;
```

Again, Date is a primary key (which I am ordering by):

```
describe Fitness;
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Date             | date          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
```

Comment: How big is the data in the `GeoJSON` column?

Comment: The JSON object returned is About 10 MB in size. It's a map of all routes I have ran/walked/cycled - and I need it to be inclusive so size will go up from there with time, too.

Comment: Well, 10MB is bigger than 1024KB, so there's your answer.

Comment: But theoretically if your using primary keys it's clean and you shouldn't have to adjust the sort buffer in any circumstance if your query is proper, right?

Comment: You’re reading data from a derived-table (the subquery, with UNIONs). While I’d expect MySQL to be able to optimise for this case (and maybe prior to version 8 it did) it clearly isn’t and is copying all of the results into the ordering buffer. That said, I’m not familiar with MySQL’s internals, but 10MB is waaaaay too big for a non-BLOB field.

Comment: Is there any way to add primary keys to a derived sub query table, without creating a separate query to make a temp table, in memory so I can work around this limitation?

Comment: Same issues here, but my JSON columns are barely ~10kb and I'm not even SELECT-ing from a subquery (although I have an inner join).